# how to check if all the numbers are swapped in an array?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to make the sort() method myself with a function.

```
function arrange(arr) {
                var arrangedList = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                                if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                                                var tmp = arr[i + 1];
                                                arr[i + 1] = arr[i]
                                                arr[i] = tmp;
                                }
                                arrangedList.push(arr[i]);
                }
                return arrangedList;
}
```

It swaps locations as I wanted, but the problem is that it swap only once.
if I call the function with [7,1,6,2] it will work like that :

```
[1,7,6,2]
[1,6,7,2]
[1,6,2,7]
```

- and here it stops. it won't check again if 6 is bigger than 2 and then swap.
  How can I solve it?

You can see my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ronilitman/zr5wh2js/).

Comment: Right off the bat I can pretty safely say that the absence of a nested iterator loop within your first `for` loop (or vice versa) is a bad sign. Check out [bubble sort algorithms](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/07/09/friday-algorithms-javascript-bubble-sort/) if you're looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is called a `bubble sort`.  This sort can potentially take as many iterations to complete as there are items in the array - 1.  For example, the array `[2,3,4,5,1]` will take four iterations to complete.

You should add a second for loop that repeats the iteration.

```
function arrange(arr) {
    var arrangedList = arr;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                var tmp = arrangedList[j + 1];
                arrangedList[j + 1] = arrangedList[j];
                arrangedList[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    return arrangedList;
}
```

You can make this algorithm more efficient by checking at each iteration to see if at least one change has been made, and returning as soon as an iteration makes no changes to the array.

Comment: Is one more for loop is enough? Because as you said, we can' know how many swaps there are.

Comment: Yes.  The extra for loop ensures that we iterate n - 1 times through the array (where n is the length of the array).  This is the maximum that could be required.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code from the [link](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/07/09/friday-algorithms-javascript-bubble-sort/) I mentioned in the comments. It implements a bubble sort:

```
var a = [34, 203, 3, 746, 200, 984, 198, 764, 9];

function bubbleSort(a)
{
    var swapped;
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (var i=0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
            if (a[i] > a[i+1]) {
                var temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swapped);
}

bubbleSort(a);
console.log(a);         //[3, 9, 34, 198, 200, 203, 746, 764, 984]
```

Answer (score 1):

you will have to use one more loop like this  :

```
function arrange(arr) {
                for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                for (var i = j; i < arr.length; i++) {

                                if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                                                var tmp = arr[i + 1];
                                                arr[i + 1] = arr[i]
                                                arr[i] = tmp;
                                }

                }}
                return arr;
}

console.log(arrange([7, 1, 2, 6]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function arrange(arr) {

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                var tmp = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = tmp;
            }

        }
    }
    return arr ;
}
```